# NameError, uninitialized constant Vote - namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The error appeared when I used namespace in routes to put things into a folder. When things(controllers, view files etc) are not in a special folder, it works just fine.
You basically click vote to get the business to be promoted (there are 'promotion' and 'vote' models as well). I just wanted to test Factual API.

The error happens when I perform a search query.

> Business::Bar.promoted_factual
>
> app/models/business/bar.rb, line 111

```
 def promoted_factual params_query, place, query  

  promoted_factual_ids = Vote.promoted_factual_ids params_query, place
  promoted_factual_ids.reject! { |id| !Vote.find_by_factual_id(id).live_vote? }
```

> Business::BarsController#promoted_factual
>
> app/controllers/business/bars_controller.rb, line 81

```
def promoted_factual
  @promoted_factual = Bar.promoted_factual params[:query], params[:place], @query
  ...
end
```

routes

```
namespace :business do 

  match 'lsearch' => "bars#lsearch", via: [:get]
  post 'vote' => 'votes#create', as: :vote

  resources :bars

end
```

Comment: Please share your routes.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error, `NameError, uninitialized constant Vote` you do not have a Model named `Vote` in `app/models` folder. Hence, you get the error.

Again, if you have Vote class but it is residing `app/models/business` directory then you should access it as `Business::Vote`. For example: `promoted_factual` should look like:

```
def promoted_factual params_query, place, query      
  promoted_factual_ids = Business::Vote.promoted_factual_ids params_query, place
  promoted_factual_ids.reject! { |id| !Business::Vote.find_by_factual_id(id).live_vote? }    
end
```